# How to get last record of details table in Master-Details tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How I can get last record of details table in Master-Details tables?

for example in Northwind database I want to get last record of order details table per `OrderID`

thanks

---

**Edit 1)**

I try this:

```
WITH NthRowCTE AS 
( 
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY od.OrderID,od.ProductID) AS RNum 
        ,od.Quantity,od.OrderID, od.ProductID
    FROM [Order Details] od 
) 
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM NthRowCTE GROUP BY RNum,Quantity,OrderID,ProductID ORDER BY RNum DESC
```

but I don't know How to connect this with every orderID

Comment: I first try to use ROW_Number but I couldn't get answer.please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `partition by` part of the window function. This will reset the counter when in encounters a new OrderID and allows `where rnum = 1` to work.

Since you want the last order detail record per order you use  `ORDER BY od.OrderDetailID DESC` to ensure this. (this assumes there's an ID to use. It could be a date or line number)

```
 WITH NthRowCTE AS 
( 
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By od.OrderID  ORDER BY od.OrderDetailID DESC ) AS RNum 
        ,od.Quantity,od.OrderID, od.ProductID
    FROM [Order Details] od 
) 
SELECT  * FROM NthRowCTE 
WHERE RNum = 1
```

Comment: thanks it works.if I have not `OrderDetailID` How I can sort and get last record?

Comment: just sort descending by whatever identifies it as the last record